# How to subset (without filtering) multiple columns from a data frame in R

Tags: r

I'm sorry this may have been done to death, but all the answers I've found veer all over the map into extreme exotica.  I can subset using [[]] (I've learned from stackoverflow that I'm *not* supposed to use subset() and similar for my scripts, since they're intended for interactive use) for a *single* column, but I can't figure out how to make the leap to more than one column.  These two work, of course:

```
outcomeA <- outcome[['Hospital.Name']]
outcomeB <- outcome[['TX]]
```

But I've tried a dozen permutations to get *both* of those columns, like so:

```
outcomeC <- outcome[[c('Hospital.Name', 'TX')]]   (gives "subscript out of bound")
outcomeC <- outcome[c('Hospital.Name', 'TX')]     (gives "undefined columns selected")
```

etc, but they all fail.   Can someone please put me out of my misery and help me select more than one column?

Thanks - Ed

Comment: Are you sure `TX` is a column? This example works `dd<-data.frame(Hospital.Name="a", TX="b"); dd[c("Hospital.Name","TX")]`

Comment: Should be single square brackets with a leading comma, i.e.: `outcome[,c("Hospital.Name", "TX")]`

Comment: You are right, it's not a column.  Sorry, I must have been wrapped around the axle with countless different variations, most of which result in incomprehensible error messages.  Thanks again, and sorry again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try this with a comma and single brackets

```
  outcomeC <- outcome[,c('Hospital.Name', 'TX')]
```

Also you can only get column names that exist in your data. check them against:

```
 names(outcome)
```

Comment: But it should have also worked with `dd[c("Hospital.Name","TX")]` if that's the case. I'm guessing one of those isn't really a column name.

Comment: OP is using double brackets. that is the problem